# how to retrieve a text from textfield out of main method

Tags: java, swing, frame

What I want to design is with this code is when I enter any text into the Textfield, then hit the button to save it. So I've been trying few ways, but I could not solve that command prompt shows me an empty space...

When I tried the source code into the "main" method, it was working well like what I expected..

Here is my source code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class testListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = new TxtField().savedTxt();

        System.out.println("ActionPerformed :" + s);
    }

}

public class TxtField {

    static JTextField jtf;
    JFrame jf;
    JButton jbtn;

    static String temp;

    public TxtField() {

        jtf = new JTextField(10);
        jf = new JFrame("JFrame");
        jbtn = new JButton("OK");

        jf.add(jtf);
        jf.add(jbtn);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(300, 300);
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtf.addActionListener(new testListener());
        jbtn.addActionListener(new testListener());

    }

    public String savedTxt() {
        temp = jtf.getText();
        System.out.println("Temp is :" + temp);
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TxtField();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain **clearly** what's not working and ask a specific question.

Comment: @Manu Hi, I can't get the text I've put into the textfield after click the button.
command prompt shows like this :
Temp is :
ActionPerformed :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new TxtField when the action is called, instead of referencing the one that invoked the action:

```
String s = new TxtField().savedTxt();
```

Try making TxtField itself the ActionListener:

```
public class TxtField implements ActionListener
```

Then reference the current instance:

```
jtf.addActionListener(this);
jbtn.addActionListener(this);
```

Then reference the JTextField in the current instance:

```
String s = savedTxt();
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! It works well !! Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are close...You can do something like this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {
    Test t;
    static JTextField jtf;
    JFrame jf;
    JButton jbtn;

    static String temp;

    public Test() {
        t = this;
        class testListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s = jtf.getText();
                t.savedTxt();
                System.out.println("ActionPerformed :" + s);
            }

        }

        jtf = new JTextField(10);
        jf = new JFrame("JFrame");
        jbtn = new JButton("OK");

        jf.add(jtf);
        jf.add(jbtn);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(300, 300);
        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jtf.addActionListener(new testListener());
        jbtn.addActionListener(new testListener());


    }

    public String savedTxt() {
        temp = jtf.getText();
        System.out.println("Temp is :" + temp);
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
    }

}
```

The problem is you are creating a `new Instance` of your class in the `actionPerformed` event instead of using the one you already have...
`String s = new TxtField().savedTxt();`
This is calling `savedTxt()` on the new instance instead of the one you already have which has the text you typed.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'm gonna try the source code and try to make it mine :)